# Meaning of solutions of an equation of state

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

> **Question** Let $p \geq 0, V \geq Nb, N > 0$. Now we are given the equation of state
>
> $$p+a\left(\frac{N}{V}\right)=\frac{Nk_BT}{V-b} \tag 1$$
>
> Classify the solutions of the equation of state as a function of temperature.

How does one solutions of the equation of state as a function of temperature? I'm not really sure what it means by solutions of $(1)$. What classification are we looking for?

Comment: Without more context, how should we know what classification you are looking for?

Comment: will edit this now

Comment: The eos looks to be linear in T, so it should be straight-forward to solve for it (unless your first question isn't actually about that).

Comment: I cant give any more context. It just seems really strange to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a typo in the equation, this is the Van der Waals equation of state. You need to plot the isotherms on a $PV$ diagram for different values of $T$, and you will find that the equation predicts a region of liquid phase where the isotherms develop both a maximum and minimum.

I won't say more since this is obviously a homework question. If you run into difficulties taking it forward from here Googling will find you a million articles on the subject.